# Drag and drop project to references folder

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, project-reference

(Visual Studio 2012)

Is there any way to create a solution reference by simple dragging the solution item (project) inside the other's project references folder? Like this?

http://i.snag.gy/p692V.jpg

Some kind of plugin or add in or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know of any Visual Studio add-in or extension that does this and I did not see when when searched. I believe that it would be useful if the feature adds the dropped reference quickly with no dialogs or prompts. This would be nice if R# had this feature. Maybe suggesting this feature to M$ (for the next VS) or JetBrains would be a good idea. Also, the reference Manager in VS 2012 is much better, faster and lower-friction than in previous versions, but I can see that project references *could* be added much faster if this feature existed. I like the idea. You could also build the extension yourself. :-)